# Как использовать репозиторий без сущности в symfony 3.4

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, symfony, symfony3

В symfony 3.4 пишу отдельную админку для админа
Вот мой security.yml:

```
security:

    providers:
        users_db:
            entity:
                class: AppBundle:User
                property: email

        admin_db:
            memory:
                users:
                    admin:
                        password: root
                        roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN'


    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: bcrypt
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        admin:
            pattern: ^/admin
            provider: admin_db
            anonymous: ~
#            logout_on_user_change: true

            form_login:
                login_path: admin_login
                check_path: admin_login
                default_target_path: admin_homepage

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /

        main:
            pattern: ^/
            provider: users_db
            anonymous: ~
            logout_on_user_change: true
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate
            # http_basic: ~

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html
            form_login:
                login_path: user_login
                check_path: user_login
                default_target_path: user_profile

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

В связи с тем что логин-пароль для админа хранится в памяти мне не нужна таблица admin в базе данных. А соответственно не нужна и сущность admin

Но мне нужен репозиторий, где бы я писал DQL - запросы к БД для admin.
Я вручную создал файл AdminRepository.php в папке Repository, но симфони не видит этот репозиторий.
Тогда я вручную также создал сущность Admin. Но теперь симфони требует от меня primary key. Попробовал решить эту проблему, приведя сущность admin к виду:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Admin
 *
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AdminRepository")
 */
class Admin
{

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

}
```

Но все равно симфони ругается:

```
No identifier/primary key specified for Entity "AppBundle\Entity\Admin". Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key.
```

Как быть если мне не нужна таблица в базе данных (ведь данные для пользователя хранятся в файле security.yml). Но нужен репозиторий, где бы я писал запросы специально для админа?
Какой тут выход?
К какому виду привести сущность Admin в моем случае?

Comment: Если у вас нет сущности Admin, то зачем вообще репозиторий?

Comment: u_mulder, вы невнимательно прочитали мой вопрос. Данные для админа хранятся в файле security.yml, они не хранятся в базе данных. Соответственно таблица admin мне не нужна!! А вот репозиторий для админа нужен: чтобы хранить запросы, которые выполняются только для админа - количество пользователей на сайте, количество отзывов, колчество комментариев и т. д. Если же я пропишу первичный ключ - он создаст мне НЕНУЖНУЮ ПУСТУЮ таблицу при первой же миграции или doctrine:schema:update !!!

Comment: Это вы вероятно невнимательно что-то читаете. Чтобы получить число отзывов - надо обратиться в репозиторий отзывов, чтобы получить число комментариев - надо обратиться в репозиторий комментариев и т.д. И так как я не вижу у вас запроса на получение количества администраторов, то и репозиторий для администраторов вам не нужен.

Comment: Когда часть кода необходимо вынести из контроллера, но при этом необходимо реализовать и нативные запросы, то отдельный репозиторий нужен. Как всегда в русском сегменте не стараются подсказать, а только говорят: "вам это не надо"...